# Reading XML Data using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, ado.net

I have a stored procedure that creates an XML document. I then have the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetModuleInstallerManifestXML", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mod_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250)).Value = this.ModuleName;

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                manifestXmlList.Add(reader[]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to add the xml data row by row into a list and then write that list to a file, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5424250/5358389

```
string xmlString = string.Empty;
using (XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
{            
     XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(reader);
     x.Save("filePath");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.