# XML generation using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

My goal is to generate xml structure in this format

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<return xmlns:rmas="value here" xmlns:xsi="value here" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="value here">
   <header>
      <return-code>""</return-code>
      <return-desc>""</return-desc>
      <as-at-date>""</as-at-date>
      <operator-code>""</operator-code>
   </header>
   <body>
         <scheme>
           <code>10050</code>
              <employer>
                    <empr-code></empr-code>
                    <data>
                       <serial-no />
                       <pin />
                       <employer-contribution />
                       <employee-contribution />
                       <voluntary-contribution />
                       <total-contribution />
                    </data>
               </employer>
        </scheme>
        <scheme>
           <code>10100</code>
              <employer>
                    <empr-code></empr-code>
                    <data>
                       <serial-no />
                       <pin />
                       <employer-contribution />
                       <employee-contribution />
                       <voluntary-contribution />
                       <total-contribution />
                    </data>
               </employer>
          </scheme>
          [...]
    </body>
  </return>
```

This is the sample of the data I am consuming

```
scheme-code emp-code        pin            empr-contr   empyee-contr    total   total-vol-cont
10050       PR0000395010    PEN200386572133 54777.28    43821.82       108599.1  10000  
10050       PR0000679771    PEN200629902715 65528.34    0              215528.34 150000 
10050       PR0000007340    PEN200629902715 0           65528.34       215528.34 150000 
10050       PU000035E001    PEN100786299723 10570.34    10570.34       21140.68  0      
10050       TCF000615630    PEN100786299723 12060.15    12060.16       24120.31  0      
10050       TCF000615630    PEN100786299723 12204.98    12204.99       24409.97  0      
10050       PR0000615630    PEN100144364216 10945.19    13681.49       24626.68  0      
10050       PR0000615630    PEN100453089112 14319.32    17899.15       32218.47  0      
10050       PR0000615630    PEN200742682512 13116.33    16395.41       29511.74  0      
10100       PRTEMP005022    PEN100940140007 792         990            1782      0  
10100       PRTEMP005022    PEN100799131715 2375        2970           5345      0
10100       PRTEMP005022    PEN100799212715 831.6       1039.5         1871.1    0
```

In the body tag, I'd like to group the data first by the scheme-code and inside the code, group the data by the emp-code in that scheme and then by the  data(pin, empr-contr,empyee-contr...)  having the empr-code. The serial-no(int) for each data tag will be 0,1,2,3....T999 depending on the number of data tags in the parent employer tag. Please see further example below

```
<scheme>
  <code>10050</code>
  [...]
  <employer>
      <empr-code>PR0000615630</empr-code>
         <data>
            <serial-no>1</serial-no>
            <pin>PEN100144364216</pin>
            <employer-contribution>10945.19</employer-contribution>
            <employee-contribution>13681.49</employee-contribution>
            <voluntary-contribution>0.00</voluntary-contribution>
            <total>32218.47</total>
         </data>
         <data>
            <serial-no>2</serial-no>
            <pin>PEN100453089112</pin>
            <employer-contribution>14319.32</employer-contribution>
            <employee-contribution>17899.15/employee-contribution>
            <voluntary-contribution>0.00</voluntary-contribution>
            <total>32218.47</total>
         </data>
      <data>
         <serial-no>T9999</serial-no>
         <pin>PEN200742682512</pin>
         <employer-contribution>13116.33</employer-contribution>
         <employee-contribution>16395.41</employee-contribution>
         <voluntary-contribution>0.00</voluntary-contribution>
         <total>29511.74</total>
      </data>
 </employer>
 [...]
</scheme>
```

How can I generate it using XMLDocument or XMLWriter

Comment: You should create a class structure to represent the XML. Then read the data from database and populate class objects with the data and then serialize it to XML. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization

Comment: Creating a class in this case just doubles the code since you have to fill the classes before exporting the xml.  The number of descendant in the xml is deep so there are lots of classes.  The input is a flat table and is much easier to just parse manually.   There is no schema to automatically generate the classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following xml linq. I put your input file into a text file and then read into DataTable. Then create XML from table :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        static XDocument doc;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReadData(INPUT_FILENAME);
            dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("scheme-code"))
                .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("emp-code"))
                .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("pin"))
                .CopyToDataTable();

            CreateXml();
            doc.Save(OUTPUT_FILENAME);

        }
        static void ReadData(string filename)
        {
            int rowNumber = 0;
            string line = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(INPUT_FILENAME);

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] splitData = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();

                if (++rowNumber == 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < splitData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (i < 3)
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(splitData[i], typeof(string));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(splitData[i], typeof(decimal));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                    for (int i = 0; i < splitData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (i < 3)
                        {
                            newRow[i] = splitData[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newRow[i] = decimal.Parse(splitData[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        static void CreateXml()
        {
            string xmlns_rmas = "value here";
            string xmlns_xsi = "value here";
            string xmlns_noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "value here";
            string xmlIdentFormat =
                "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" +
                "<return" +
                    " xmlns:rmas=\"{0}\"" +
                    " xmlns:xsi=\"{1}\"" +
                    " xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"{2}\">" +
                "</return>";
            string xmlIdent = string.Format(xmlIdentFormat, xmlns_rmas, xmlns_xsi, xmlns_noNamespaceSchemaLocation);
            doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlIdent);

            XElement _return = doc.Root;

            string returnCode = "";
            string returnDesc = "";
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            string operatorCode = "";
            XElement header = new XElement("header", new object[] {
                new XElement("return-code", returnCode),
                new XElement("return-desc", returnDesc),
                new XElement("as-at-date", date),
                new XElement("operator-code", operatorCode)
            });
            _return.Add(header);

            XElement body = new XElement("body");
            _return.Add(body);


            foreach(var schemeGroup in dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("scheme-code")))
            {
                XElement scheme = new XElement("scheme");
                body.Add(scheme);
                XElement code = new XElement("code", schemeGroup.Key);
                scheme.Add(code);
                foreach(var empCodeGroup in schemeGroup.GroupBy(y => y.Field<string>("emp-code")))
                {
                    XElement employer = new XElement("employer");
                    scheme.Add(employer);
                    int serialNumber = 0;

                    foreach(var pinGroup in empCodeGroup.GroupBy(y => y.Field<string>("pin")))
                    {
                        if (serialNumber == 0)
                        {
                            XElement emprCode = new XElement("empr-code", empCodeGroup.Key);
                            employer.Add(emprCode);
                        }
                        foreach (DataRow row in pinGroup)
                        {

                            XElement data = new XElement("data");
                            employer.Add(data);
                            if ((empCodeGroup.Count() > 1) && (serialNumber == empCodeGroup.Count() - 1))
                            {
                                data.Add(new XElement("serial-no", "T999"));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                data.Add(new XElement("serial-no", serialNumber));
                            }

                            data.Add(new XElement("pin", pinGroup.Key));
                            data.Add(new XElement("employer-contribution", row.Field<decimal>("empr-contr")));
                            data.Add(new XElement("employee-contribution", row.Field<decimal>("empyee-contr")));
                            data.Add(new XElement("voluntary-contribution", row.Field<decimal>("total-vol-cont")));
                            data.Add(new XElement("total-contribution", row.Field<decimal>("total")));

                            serialNumber++;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Looking what I really wanted. A big thank you for your help. These are my observations. Please kindly assist: (a) the "pin" field is same as the "emp-code". (b) emp-code tag/element should not be inside the data tag/element (c) emp-code with repeated values in the scheme should have data tags to the number of times it is repeated. i.e employer code "PR0000615630" should have 3 data tags/elements with serial-no 1,2 and T999 because it is repeated 3 times in the scheme-code. The serial-no should not continue to the next employer tag/element rather it should start a new sequence. Thanks a lot

Comment: How can I can I thank you enough. You've been a life saver. I'd like to have only one emp-code in the employer tag for emp-codes whose values are repeated in the scheme and then take the last serial-no as T999 in the data tag/element if they are more than one. Is it possible?

Comment: Again very simple.  This data must be real old.   I haven't seen T999 since they stop using high speed printers with the holes on the edge.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server you can use a data adapter to fill the datatable instead of reading from a text file. the rest of the code will be the same

Comment: I updated code to start serial number at zero after reading the posting again.

Comment: You did not complete you last comment.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks for your help. I'm now using datatable to fetch the data but I observed that if 2(or more) same pins belong to the same emp-code also in the same scheme, the contribution values are summed up and returned as one data tag/element rather it should be repeated i.e( broken into different data tags) but within the same employer tag/element. What do I do?

Comment: I saw same when I originally wrote the code and that is why a put the SUM into the code.  To create a separate tag for each pin means to add another foreach on the variable pinGroup : foreach(DataRow row in pinGroup){}

Comment: Can you please help update the code? It's not coming together

Comment: I changed one line back to the original code :  if ((empCodeGroup.Count() > 1) && (serialNumber == empCodeGroup.Count() - 1))

Comment: perfect! Thanks for your help. Appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Load Data to the DataSet and use Write XML. This is the simplest way you can try

```
DataSet oDsData = new DataSet();
oDsData.WriteXml("path", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but how will it take care of the inner tags/elements?

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the solution if your data is in MSSQL server. I assumed your data resides in a table (`##tmp_test`) in database.

```
    public string GetXML()
    {
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = document.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);

        XmlElement root = document.DocumentElement;
        document.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);
        var returnElement =  document.CreateElement( "return");
        returnElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:rmas", "value here");
        returnElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "value here");
        returnElement.SetAttribute("noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "value here");

        var header = document.CreateElement("header");
        var rc = document.CreateElement("return-code");
        rc.InnerText = "\"\"";
        header.AppendChild(rc);
        var rd = document.CreateElement("return-desc");
        rd.InnerText = "\"\"";
        header.AppendChild(rd);
        var aad = document.CreateElement("as-at-date");
        aad.InnerText = "\"\"";
        header.AppendChild(aad);
        var oc = document.CreateElement("operator-code");
        oc.InnerText = "\"\"";
        header.AppendChild(oc);
        returnElement.AppendChild(header);

        var body = document.CreateElement("body");
        body.InnerXml = GetBodyXML();

        returnElement.AppendChild(body);

        document.AppendChild(returnElement);

        return document.OuterXml;
    }

    private string GetBodyXML()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = @"
                    SELECT 1 AS Tag
                        ,NULL AS Parent
                        ,[Scheme].[scheme-code] AS [scheme!1!code!ELEMENT]
                        ,NULL AS [employer!2!empr-code!ELEMENT]
                        ,NULL AS [data!3!serial-no!ELEMENT]
                        ,NULL AS [data!3!pin!ELEMENT]
                        ,NULL AS [data!3!employer-contribution!ELEMENT]
                        ,NULL AS [data!3!employee-contribution!ELEMENT]
                        ,NULL AS [data!3!voluntary-contribution!ELEMENT]
                        ,NULL AS [data!3!total!ELEMENT]
                    FROM ##tmp_test [Scheme]

                    UNION

                    SELECT 2 AS Tag
                        ,1 AS Parent
                        ,[Scheme].[scheme-code] AS code
                        ,[Scheme].[emp-code] AS [empr-code]
                        ,NULL AS [serial-no]
                        ,NULL AS pin
                        ,NULL AS [employer-contribution]
                        ,NULL AS [employee-contribution]
                        ,NULL AS [voluntary-contribution]
                        ,NULL AS [total]
                    FROM ##tmp_test [Scheme]

                    UNION

                    SELECT 3 AS Tag
                        ,2 AS Parent
                        ,[Scheme].[scheme-code] AS code
                        ,[Scheme].[emp-code] AS [empr-code]
                        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                            PARTITION BY [Scheme].[scheme-code]
                            ,[Scheme].[emp-code] ORDER BY pin
                            ) AS [serial-no]
                        ,[Scheme].pin AS [pin]
                        ,[Scheme].[empr-contr] AS [employer-contribution]
                        ,[Scheme].[empyee-contr] AS [employee-contribution]
                        ,[Scheme].[total-vol-cont] AS [voluntary-contribution]
                        ,[Scheme].total AS [total]
                    FROM ##tmp_test [Scheme]
                    ORDER BY [scheme!1!code!ELEMENT]
                        ,[employer!2!empr-code!ELEMENT]
                    FOR XML EXPLICIT
                    ";
                //Better approach to read all xml - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40775242/1010395
                using (XmlReader xmlReader = command.ExecuteXmlReader())
                {
                    XPathDocument xp = new XPathDocument(xmlReader);
                    XPathNavigator xn = xp.CreateNavigator();
                    return xn.OuterXml;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'll feedback shortly

Comment: I had this error: invalid column name scheme!1!code!ELEMENT

Comment: @hopeforall In which line are you getting this error?  View running [Sql Fiddle Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/50cb6/2/0)