# get the last xml descendant of an element in a parent element in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to get the count of the last descendant of the data element in the scheme element and add an element to the data element base on the count. Here's my code

```
 [...]
 if ((scheme.Descendants("data").Count() > 1 ) && (serialNumber == scheme.Descendants("data").Count()))
 {
    data.Add(new XElement("serial-no", "T9999"));
 }
 else
 {
    data.Add(new XElement("serial-no", serialNumber));
 }
 [...]
```

The **serialNumber** is auto incremented. 
The output is not favourable as this is what I am getting

```
 <scheme>
  <code>10050</code>
  <data>
    <serial-no>1</serial-no>
  </data>
  <data>
    <serial-no>T9999</serial-no>
  </data>
  <data>
    <serial-no>T9999</serial-no>
  </data>
</scheme>
```

Below is what I'd like to get

```
 <scheme>
  <code>10050</code>
  <data>
    <serial-no>1</serial-no>
  </data>
  <data>
    <serial-no>2</serial-no>
  </data>
  [...]
  <data>
    <serial-no>T9999</serial-no>
  </data>
</scheme>
 <scheme>
  <code>10000</code>
  <data>
    <serial-no>1</serial-no>
  </data>
  <data>
    <serial-no>2</serial-no>
  </data>
  [...]
  <data>
    <serial-no>T9999</serial-no>
  </data>
</scheme>
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: int count = doc.Descendants("scheme").First().Elements("data").Count();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME1 = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        static XDocument doc;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReadData(INPUT_FILENAME);
            dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("scheme-code"))
                .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("emp-code"))
                .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("pin"))
                .CopyToDataTable();

            CreateXml();
            doc.Save(OUTPUT_FILENAME);

            XElement t9999 = null;
            XElement newData = null;
            //add new node
            foreach (XElement scheme in doc.Descendants("scheme"))
            {
                //foreach (XElement employer in scheme.Descendants("employer"))
                //{
                t9999 = scheme.Elements("data").Where(x => (string)x.Element("serial-no") == "T9999").FirstOrDefault();
                int maxSerialNumber = scheme.Descendants("serial-no").Where(x => (string)x != "T9999").Max(x => (int)x);

                string serialNumberStr = (t9999 == null) ? "T9999" : (maxSerialNumber + 1).ToString();

                if (t9999 == null)
                {
                    t9999 = NewData(
                         "T9999",
                         "",  //pin
                         0.0M,  //emplorer contribution
                         0.0M,  //employee contribution
                         0.0M, //total volumn contribution
                         0.0M  // total
                     );

                    scheme.Add(newData);
                }
                else
                {
                    newData = NewData(
                        (maxSerialNumber + 1).ToString(),
                        "",  //pin
                        0.0M,  //emplorer contribution
                        0.0M,  //employee contribution
                        0.0M, //total volumn contribution
                        0.0M  // total
                    );

                    t9999.ReplaceWith(new object[] { newData, t9999 });
                }
                //}

            }

            doc.Save(OUTPUT_FILENAME1);

        }
        static void ReadData(string filename)
        {
            int rowNumber = 0;
            string line = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(INPUT_FILENAME);

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] splitData = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();

                if (++rowNumber == 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < splitData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (i < 3)
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(splitData[i], typeof(string));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(splitData[i], typeof(decimal));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                    for (int i = 0; i < splitData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (i < 3)
                        {
                            newRow[i] = splitData[i];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newRow[i] = decimal.Parse(splitData[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        static void CreateXml()
        {
            string xmlns_rmas = "value here";
            string xmlns_xsi = "value here";
            string xmlns_noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "value here";
            string xmlIdentFormat =
                "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" +
                "<return" +
                    " xmlns:rmas=\"{0}\"" +
                    " xmlns:xsi=\"{1}\"" +
                    " xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"{2}\">" +
                "</return>";
            string xmlIdent = string.Format(xmlIdentFormat, xmlns_rmas, xmlns_xsi, xmlns_noNamespaceSchemaLocation);
            doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlIdent);

            XElement _return = doc.Root;

            string returnCode = "";
            string returnDesc = "";
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            string operatorCode = "";
            XElement header = new XElement("header", new object[] {
                new XElement("return-code", returnCode),
                new XElement("return-desc", returnDesc),
                new XElement("as-at-date", date),
                new XElement("operator-code", operatorCode)
            });
            _return.Add(header);

            XElement body = new XElement("body");
            _return.Add(body);


            foreach (var schemeGroup in dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("scheme-code")))
            {
                XElement scheme = new XElement("scheme");
                body.Add(scheme);
                XElement code = new XElement("code", schemeGroup.Key);
                scheme.Add(code);
                foreach (var empCodeGroup in schemeGroup.GroupBy(y => y.Field<string>("emp-code")))
                {
                    //XElement employer = new XElement("employer");
                    //scheme.Add(employer);
                    int serialNumber = 0;

                    foreach (var pinGroup in empCodeGroup.GroupBy(y => y.Field<string>("pin")))
                    {
                        if (serialNumber == 0)
                        {
                            XElement emprCode = new XElement("empr-code", empCodeGroup.Key);
                            scheme.Add(emprCode);
                        }
                        foreach (DataRow row in pinGroup)
                        {
                            string serialNumberStr = serialNumber.ToString();

                            if ((empCodeGroup.Count() > 1) && (serialNumber == empCodeGroup.Count() - 1))
                            {
                                serialNumberStr = "T9999";
                            }


                            XElement data = NewData(
                                serialNumberStr,
                                pinGroup.Key,
                                row.Field<decimal>("empr-contr"),
                                row.Field<decimal>("empyee-contr"),
                                row.Field<decimal>("total-vol-cont"),
                                 row.Field<decimal>("total")
                            );
                            scheme.Add(data);
                            serialNumber++;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        static XElement NewData(string serialNumber, string pin, decimal employerContribution, decimal employeeContribution, decimal voluntaryContribution, decimal totalContribution)
        {
            XElement data = new XElement("data");
            data.Add(new XElement("serial-no", serialNumber));
            data.Add(new XElement("pin", pin));
            data.Add(new XElement("employer-contribution", employerContribution));
            data.Add(new XElement("employee-contribution", employeeContribution));
            data.Add(new XElement("voluntary-contribution", voluntaryContribution));
            data.Add(new XElement("total-contribution", totalContribution));

            return data;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59316018 You helped with it. I want to get the total count of data elements in each scheme element and add new element to the data element accordingly

Comment: This looks perfect. It is possible to have the total of employer-contribution,employee-contribution,voluntary-contribution and total for that employer in the data element housing the serial number with T999 which is the last data item in the employer data

Comment: Yes.  I though I did a total back in December with my original first answer.  Do you need it both when originally generating the xml or just when updating?

Comment: Which is better. When generating or updating? I just noticed that the data is duplicated by 1 item in each employer code. i.e if there is one data element in the employer element, we'll have a total of 3 data elements- the real data, the duplicated data and T999 data. If there are more than one data elements, the first data element is duplicated. I'm not sure which line of code we need to update. Kindly help

Comment: The totals needs to be in both if you are still reading from the data table.  I do not know where the values are coming from for XElement newData so I just used the first data element and change the serial number.  So the serial number should be correct but all the other data need to be updated (or newData should be a new element.

Comment: I added a new method NewData to avoid duplicating code.

Comment: Great. Everything looks perfect. I summed each row using the empCodeGroup grouping. Thank you again

Comment: Kindly guide on how to create a new node like we introduced here to replace the T9999 value accordingly following the structure for one of the schema element below. Here the data element is no longer a child element to the employer element in scheme element. Rather it is a direct child element to scheme element
`<scheme>
      <code>10100</code>
      <data>
        <serial-no>1</serial-no>
        [...]
      </data>
     // more data elements
      [...]
      <data>
        <serial-no>T999</serial-no>
        [...]
      </data>
    </scheme>`

Comment: Code would look very similar to the method NewData().

Comment: This is what I did
`foreach (XElement data in doc.Descendants("data"))
{
 XElement t999 = data.Elements("data").Where(x => (string)x.Element("serial-no") == "T9999").FirstOrDefault();
 int maxSerialNumber = data.Descendants("serial-no").Where(x => (string)x != "T9999").Max(x => (int)x);
 XElement newData = XElement.Parse(data.Element("data").ToString());
 if (t999 == null)
 {
  newData.Element("serial-no").SetValue("T9999");
  data.Add(newData);
 }
 else
 {
  newData.Element("serial-no").SetValue(maxSerialNumber + 1);
  t999.ReplaceWith(new object[] { newData, t999 });
 }
}`

Comment: That code is not working. Where did I not get it right?

Comment: I updated the code.  Mode changes were needed because I had to get the node scheme.

Comment: The data element is no longer in the employer element again. It is directly inside scheme element

Comment: May be I mis-interpreted what you said  : "Here the data element is no longer a child element to the employer element in scheme element. Rather it is a direct child element to scheme element".  Did you mean you wanted "data" under "scheme" or that is was wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206068/discussion-between-hopeforall-and-jdweng).